# Excel: Rounding up Nearest value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Click [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vekyepqtj5ud6pm/Stackover_flow.xlsx?dl=0) for excel file.

In the Excel file based on Column B values I am finding nearest up offer price range which is in Row number 2 in Grey Color, Offer price per sqm is incremental by $50. As you can see in Yellow color values are multiplied by offer price * Land sqm.
3rd property nearest offer price range is $750. As you can see I am using multiple columns from C, D, E, F.
Instead what I want is get the "Offer Price per/sqm" value in column "G". How to do that.?

Comment: Can you please tell what is your desired output for sample cases?

Comment: do you want 750, 800, 750, <>, 800?

Comment: In Column "G" I want whatever the nearest matching per/sqm value like cell "E3", I want that value in G3 using formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you are not pretty clear about the output you want, I think you want to round the offer price to nearest 50.  If so, use this in `G3` (and copy down)

```
=MROUND(A3/B3, 50)
```

this will return $700 as nearest offer price.  However, if you want to round only upwards i.e. towards $750, use this (and copy down)

```
=CEILING(A3/B3, 50)
```

If you want either of these formulae to return values between 650 and 800 only use either of these

```
=IF(AND(CEILING(A3/B3, 50)>=650, CEILING(A3/B3, 50) <=800), CEILING(A3/B3, 50), "NA")
```

Based on your comment, perhaps you need this?

```
=IF(AND(CEILING(A3/B3, 50)>=650, CEILING(A3/B3, 50) <=800), CEILING(A3/B3, 50)*B3, "NA")
```

Comment: =CEILING(A3/B3, 50) worked for me. I tried Ceiling formula but your logic worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Please feel free to accept the answer as correct one and consider upvoting as usually desired on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is what you want.

```
[G3] =B3*INDEX($C$2:$F$2,1,MATCH("x",C3:F3,0))
```

You would mark the appropriate column with an "x" and the formula would multiply the price in row 2 of the first marked column with the number of sqm.

To simulate your example, an "x" would be placed inE3 and F3. The formula in G3 would ignore the F3 and show the price based on E2. If you add an "x" in D3 the lower price will be shown in G3.